# How can I create a login partial view in MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, authentication, passwords, partial

How can I create a login partial view in MVC 2.0?

I want to include this in several masterpages in my site since I can't use the login control in MVC.

What code do I put in the controller which will accept the username and password?

Comment: Have you worked with ASP.NET MVC before? A number of elements in your question suggest inexperience, and you don't say why the "login control" in MVC is unsuitable. I suggest you spend some time with the NerdDinner tutorial first, it should clear up a few things for you: http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default MVC project creates one for you.  Just install MVC and create a MVC project.  It will have a Master page, with a login partial view already created.